# How to get the tag "<yweather:condition>" from Yahoo Weather RSS in PHP?

Tags: php, yahoo-weather-api

```
<?php
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=VEXX0024&u=c');
    $channel = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");
    foreach($channel as $chnl)
    {
        $item = $chnl->getElementsByTagName("item");
        foreach($item as $itemgotten)
        {
            $describe = $itemgotten->getElementsByTagName("description");
            $description = $describe->item(0)->nodeValue;
            echo $description;
        }
    }
?>
```

And as you can see is a simple script who return the content of the tag  from the above url. The thing is that i dont need that content, i need the one who is inside the tag . I need the attributes **code**, **temp**, **text**. How do i do that simple with my actual code? Thanks

Ex of the tag content:

```
<yweather:condition  text="Partly Cloudy"  code="30"  temp="30"  date="Fri, 16 Jul 2010 8:30 am AST" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
echo $itemgotten->getElementsByTagNameNS(
    "http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0","condition")->item(0)->
     getAttribute("temp");
```

The key is that you have to use `getElementsByTagNameNS` instead of `getElementsByTagName` and specify `"http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"` as the namespace.

You know `yweather` is a shortcut for `http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0` because the XML file includes a `xmls` attribute:

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0"
    xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

- [`DOMElement::getAttribute`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)  — Returns value of attribute

And if you need to get anything with namespaces, there is corresponding methods ending in `NS`.