# Parsing XML (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I'm using SimpleXML . I want to get this node's *text* attribute.

```
<yweather:condition  text="Mostly Cloudy"  ......
```

I'm using this it's not working :

```
$xml->children("yweather", TRUE)->condition->attributes()->text;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP namespace simplexml problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098170/php-namespace-simplexml-problems)

Comment: Exact duplicate when using DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268976/how-to-get-the-tag-yweathercondition-from-yahoo-weather-rss-in-php

Comment: your "is not working" code is not working because you are doing it wrong: `<yweather:condition>` is a child of `rss/channel/item` while you are trying `rss/condition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access an attribute, which is stored in an array in $xml->yweather->attributes() so:

```
$attributes = $xml->condition->attributes();
$weather = $attributes['text'];
```

To deal with the namespace, you need to use children() to get the members of that namespace.

```
$weather_items = $xml->channel->item->children("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0");
```

It might help to mention that the string you showed is part of a feed, specifically the RSS formatted Yahoo Weather feed.

Answer (score 1):

Do a print_r() on $xml to see how the structure looks. From there you should be able to see how to access the information.

Comment: `SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ` . Also question edited please look again

Answer (score 0):

You would probably use $xml->condition but there may be branches before that.