# PHP and simplexml_load_file()

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My problem is this, i want to get value of yweather->code from xml file: http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265

How can i do?

Comment: You have examples here http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: @ZulkhaeryBasrul: sure you can, and well, just searching reveals this question: [How to get the tag “<yweather:condition>” from Yahoo Weather RSS in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3268976/367456) from July 2010 and for simplexml accessing namespaced elements [Parse XML with Namespace using SimpleXML](http://stackoverflow.com/q/595946/367456) from Feb 2009 or [PHP SimpleXML Namespace Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6027398/367456) from May 2011.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very good info at the said [link](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/03/yahoo-weather-api/)..