# Value of attributes of an elements with namespace

Tags: php, xml, rss, yahoo-weather-api

I am developing a weather forecast of the current weather and weather forecast for my schools website.
For this I will be using Yahoos RSS weather forecast.
In this XML file there are some values stored in attributes.
I would like to get those out with PHP.
The file can be found here:
http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12602818&u=c

The XML file states the folowing line:

```
<rss xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0">
```

The value I would like to get out is the following:

```
<yweather:condition text="Partly Cloudy" code="30" temp="22" date="Wed, 12 Jun 2013 4:20 pm CEST"/>
```

I would, for example, like to receive 'temp' from this yweather:condition.
Can anybody instruct me how this could be done with PHP?

Comment: using an XML parser - there are many for PHP

Comment: please post an instructive and valid part of the XML within your question (use edit). Thank you!

Comment: Please use the search. If we haven't this even answered specific to yahoo weather RSS, then at least it's answered with xml-namespaces in general. See [Parsing Yahoo weather RSS feed to get namespaced city element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095012/parsing-yahoo-weather-rss-feed-to-get-namespaced-city-element?rq=1) and others from the related column on the right -->

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=12602818&u=c');
$channel = $doc->getElementsByTagName("channel");
foreach($channel as $chnl){
    $item = $chnl->getElementsByTagName("item");
    foreach($item as $itemgotten){
        $curtemp = $itemgotten->getElementsByTagNameNS("http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0","condition")->item(0)->getAttribute("temp");
        echo $curtemp;
    }
}
?>
```

this fixed the issue!
Answer found here:
[How to get the tag "<yweather:condition>" from Yahoo Weather RSS in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268976/how-to-get-the-tag-yweathercondition-from-yahoo-weather-rss-in-php)