# How to access properties within an XML element

Tags: php, xml

I am using yahoo weather API to get the weather for my locality. I get an XML document back from a call to the API.
I have tried the following to access the properties in the element 'yweather:condition' with no success. I am trying to access the 'temp' in this element. I get the following error:

> 'syntax error, unexpected ':' in line ...

```
 $endpoint = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D%20560743&diagnostics=true';   
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($endpoint) or die('failed to load xml');
 $out = $xml -> diagnostics ->  yweather:condition['temp'];
 echo $out;


 <query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" yahoo:count="1" yahoo:created="2017-02-10T11:54:56Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
    <diagnostics>
       <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
       <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="7" execution-time="6">...</url>
       <user-time>8</user-time>
       <service-time>6</service-time>
       <build-version>2.0.92</build-version>
       <yweather:condition xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" code="26" date="Fri, 10 Feb 2017 11:00 AM GMT" temp="37" text="Cloudy"/>
    </diagnostics>
    <results>...</results>
</query>
```

Comment: please see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268976/how-to-get-the-tag-yweathercondition-from-yahoo-weather-rss-in-php

Comment: Not an ideal solution, but...`$out = $xml->xpath('//@temp');`